# How i can enable dictionary verification in tesseract

Tags: c#, tesseract

I use C# wrapper of tesseract - [charlesw](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract). And can't understand, why dictionary verification doesn't work. How I can enable dictionary verification? For example "EXOMPLE" - not dictionary word, change on "EXAMPLE"

```
            TesseractEngine engine = new TesseractEngine(@"tessdata/", "rus", EngineMode.TesseractOnly);

        engine.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", whiteList);

        // Tesseract Settings    
        engine.SetVariable("language_model_penalty_non_dict_word", 0.65);
        engine.SetVariable("language_model_penalty_non_freq_dict_word", 0.6);
```

Comment: Parametr "tessedit_enable_dict_correction" Don`t work too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CharlesW add "config" parametr in constructor. And now we can use dictionary verification

```
TesseractEngine engine = new TesseractEngine(@"tessdata/", "rus", EngineMode.TesseractOnly, "config");
```

Config:

```
load_system_dawg F
load_freq_dawg F
user_words_suffix user-words
user_patterns_suffix user-patterns
```